Use packages which require different python versions
I'm developing a script for a pipeline that uses various packages. Unfortunately, these packages require different versions of Python. Here is a mock example of the situation:
Main script runs on Python 3.11, and it needs package 1 & 2
Package 1 runs only on Python 3.8
Package 2 runs only on Python 3.9

What are my best options to run everything together?
The only nasty solution that crosses my mind would be to do something like:
# Some code in python 3.11
# Export (save on disk) data required by Package 1
os.system("/path/to/python38/python LaunchPackage1")
# Get/Load Package 1 results
# Export (save on disk) data required by Package 2
os.system("/path/to/python39/python LaunchPackage2")
# Get/Load Package 2 results

I do hope there is something better to do.

you might want to use some package manager to manage dependencies like poetry

Your "nasty" solution seems like the only way to do it. You can't combine them into a single python invocation.

The first thing I would do is check to see if there are updated versions of package1 and package2 that support newer python versions.

Does package1 run on exactly python 3.8, or does it run on python 3.8 or later?

@JohnGordon Package 1 is recommended on 3.8 and might support 3.9 (no guaranty) but no later for sure. Package 2 required 3.9 only. I already checked for more recent versions, but all of them still require something older than 3.10

@MateuszKiersnowski I took a quick look. How can it help with the versions issue?

Even poetry still can't combine multiple Python versions in a single process.

If package 1 and 2 are actually separate scripts that can be launched, and they can't be upgraded, and you can't use an older version of Python, why not put them in separate systems that have the correct python version, and then make separate calls in the pipeline.
So the pipeline would be run package 1 -> run package 2 -> run main script

@blueteeth How much different is this from my "nasty solution"?

@FiReTiTi fundamentally not that different, but if you used docker or similar, it would be a repeatable maintainable setup and you would not have to manage the system so much. Also if your scripts take dynamic input, your nasty solution is susceptible to some kind of injection.
